# how to maintain a requestcontext across rest datasource in GraphQL

Tags: apollo, apollo-server

I wanted to know if i have multiple resolvers and in the resolvers which extends RESTDataSource . if i get access to context using `this.context` . is that the context that server has created for that particular request ? The reason I am asking this question is :- I see when from a RESTDatSource if i call another RESTDataSource then occasionally the context is getting over ridden for the chained call to a new context ( which is based on another request to server coming in same same time frame)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which framework you are using but if you are using `ApolloServer` then you can have different context object for each request. If you can explain where exactly you are facing this issue I can help more... :)

Comment: Hello @Ravi , thanks . I use ApolloServer.In each of my resolvers class which extends RestDatasource,  I access context  using ```this.context``` . now if i call resolver y from resolver x i am passing only the payload not the context with it . so when the resolver Y is executing , it takes ```this.context``` perhaps that times (if any new request came in)  server context so the header gets overridden with a new request's header. the Payload remains as is required .

Comment: Hi @CoolOS my first question is why you are calling resolver y from x. You shouldn't directly call resolvers. GraphQL manage that for you. It calls different resolvers sometimes parallely during resolving queries. And I think that's why you are facing that issue. GraphQL mange same context object during the execution of  query if you are directly calling resolvers then it will break things in so many ways.